# Update categories of a web content in ModelListener

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I am linking a category based on the structure used by a user. Example: my structure is "A" then any content created with this structure should have the category as "A".

I've created a listener extending `BaseModelListener` on `JournalArticle` model. I override `onBeforeUpdate()` which looks like:

```
@Override
public void onBeforeUpdate(JournalArticle aModel) throws ModelListenerException {
    try {
        long[] assetCategoryIds = refactorCategories(anArticle); // this reads the structure key and updates the list of category to the correct one.
        String[] assetTagNames = getTags(anArticle); 
        long[] assetEntryLinkIds = getEntryLinkIds(anArticle);
        JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.updateAsset(anArticle.getUserId(), anArticle, assetCategoryIds, assetTagNames, assetEntryLinkIds);
    } catch (PortalException |SystemException ex) {
        throw new ModelListenerException("Cannot update the categories for articleId" + anArticle.getArticleId(), ex);
    }
}
```

where I have corrected the `categoryIds` using a set of business rules.

Following are two possible scenarios:

1. There is no category assigned:

   - In this case, the above `onBeforeUpdate()` works like a charm, and the correct category is assigned.
2. If the user assigns a category before the invocation (which can be a wrong one):

   - In this case, `onBeforeUpdate()` implementation is invoked and I am able to see the updated asset (validated using debugging), but when the complete process is done the web content does not reflect the right categories.

My understanding:
      When `updateAsset` is called it takes the changed categories. But when Hibernate is saving the content it saves the user selected category. This seems to be a bit weird to me.

So I wished to check whether there is any possible solution or API that I can use.

Also, I tried `onAfterCreate()`, `onAfterUpdate()`, `onBeforeCreate()`, but not luck.

I believe I can hook `JournalArticleService` but I wish to do this using listener if at all possible.

**Updated code based on Tobias suggestion:**

```
@Override
public void onBeforeUpdate(JournalArticle aModel) throws ModelListenerException {
    ServiceContext serviceContext = ServiceContextThreadLocal.getServiceContext();
     try {
        long[] assetCategoryIds = refactorCategories(anArticle); // this reads the structure key and updates the list of category to the correct one.
        if (serviceContext != null) {
            serviceContext.setAssetCategoryIds(assetCategoryIds);
        }
    } catch (PortalException |SystemException ex) {
        throw new ModelListenerException("Cannot update the categories for articleId" + anArticle.getArticleId(), ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to create a hook plugin and use a service wrapper to extend `JournalArticleLocalService`. I find a service hook more suitable for task. Doing this through a service hook is also a preferred way according to Liferay certification program.

In general:

- I use model listener to update the article properties before it is persisted (eg. custom url title).
- I use service hook to update the related asset entry (eg. categories and tags).

Sample extended service:

```
public class MyJournalArticleLocalService extends JournalArticleLocalServiceWrapper {

    @Override
    public JournalArticle addArticle(..., ServiceContext serviceContext) throws PortalException, SystemException {

        // set the right category in the service context, as the service context 
        // that the original service will work with can be modified here
        serviceContext.setAssetCategoryIds(refactorCategories(...));

        // delegate to the original implementation
        return super.addArticle(..., serviceContext);
    }

    @Override
    public JournalArticle updateArticle(..., , ServiceContext serviceContext) throws PortalException, SystemException {

        // set the right category in the service context, as the service context 
        // that the original service will work with can be modified here
        serviceContext.setAssetCategoryIds(refactorCategories(...));

        // delegate to the original implementation
        return super.updateArticle(..., serviceContext);
    }
}
```

With the service hook, you could update the category *before* or *after* Liferay finished persisting the article and creating / updating the related asset entry.

You can register the service hook in `liferay-hook.xml` descriptor:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hook PUBLIC "-//Liferay//DTD Hook 6.2.0//EN" "http://www.liferay.com/dtd/liferay-hook_6_2_0.dtd">

<hook>
    <service>
        <service-type>com.liferay.portlet.journal.service.JournalArticleLocalService</service-type>
        <service-impl>com.test.MyJournalArticleLocalService</service-impl>
    </service>
</hook>
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to modify the service context in your service hook instead of adding an update afterwards? Otherwise you would have a short time of an invalid category setting (from the business view), which may lead to problems if the categories are used in the workflow (fired in that short time) or if something goes wrong in the second update.

Comment: That's a very good point. Thanks. I used the sequence from my original answer for adding new unique tags (just adding, no replacing), where it wasn't a problem.

Answer (score 1):

See `JournalArticleLocalServiceImpl.addArticle()` resp. `updateArticle()`:

```
  journalArticlePersistence.update(article);

  ...

  updateAsset(userId, article, serviceContext.getAssetCategoryIds(),
    serviceContext.getAssetTagNames(),
    serviceContext.getAssetLinkEntryIds());
```

The first line `journalArticlePersistence.update(article)` will invoke your listener, while `updateAsset` will save the user provided categories. After the call to your listener.

You can get the current service context and change it from inside your listener:

```
ServiceContext serviceContext = ServiceContextThreadLocal.getServiceContext();
if (serviceContext != null) {
  serviceContext.setAssetCategoryIds(assetCategoryIds);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointers.

I was on the same track, but I stuck at a point:

As per my understanding when we add/update an article there is an event that is triggered which calls the above overridden methods

In the same I did:

ServiceContext serviceContext = ServiceContextThreadLocal.getServiceContext();

And updated the serviceContext reference with the correct categoryIds (update the post with newer code)

But when I debug I do not see this updated object being passed. I think I am making some mistake, but not yet able to track it.

Can you think of any obvious issue?

Thanks again!

Comment: Which _update object_ do you mean? `serviceContext`? Can you check if the serviceContext in the listener is the same (really ==) as in `updateArticle`?

Comment: interestingly the serviceContext object reference in the listener and the one is the updateArticle()/addArticle() is different. I was expecting that to be the same. Not sure what is wrong, as I was expecting that when we are trying to get the serviceContext then we should have the same object in the listener as that of the method invoking the listener as are getting it the context from the ServiceContextThreadLocal. What do you think? Thanks again!

Comment: When looking at the code I hoped that the service context saved in the action would be the same as the one given to `addArticle()`. But apparently it is somewhere cloned. If you are debugging anyway you could check where the `serviceContext` is coming from. But it could be that you can't acquire that instance somehow, so you will eventually need a hook. Either by wrapping `JournalArticleLocalService`, like Tomas did, or by wrapping `AssetEntryLocalService`.